# How can I make a value in JS loaded from a HTML form stay defined as JS enters draw loop

Tags: javascript, html

When I, from within the draw loop, get the HTML value it's defines, but if I load it before it enters the loop it seems to forget it.

This is the code I've narrowed it down to:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    setInterval(draw,120);
    var value = document.getElementById("uniqueID").value

    function draw() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

      if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.strokeText(value, 200, 200);
      }
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="draw();">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="uniqueID" value="5" /><br>
 </body>
</html>
```

Like this the code doesn't work. The text says that value is undefined.
But if i move the "var value = do..." to after the draw function it gets it.

I need to define the value outside of the draw function. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if i move the "var value = do..." to after the draw function it
>   gets it.

I think you're mistaken because the element with the id uniqueID does not exist anywhere outside the draw function. This because your script block is executed before there is an element with uniqueID.

You can add the whole script block after the elements are created and add the document type definition:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="uniqueID" value="5" /><br>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    setInterval(draw,120);
    var value = document.getElementById("uniqueID").value

    function draw() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

      if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.strokeText(value, 200, 200);
      }
    }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solved it perfectly! Thanks!
I'm still quite confused though. Shouldn't the it give an error when the canvas is loaded and the script that shows what should happen in the canvas hasn't been read yet?

Comment: When you get the canvas with document.getelementbyid it does exist because you do it inside the function draw and draw is called on "onload" so when the document is done loading. The variable "value" is set to document.getelementbyid... outside the draw function so that returns undefined then you get the .value property of it but you can't because undefined has no properties.

Comment: you can have a canvas element without any script, that should not cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this in the head when the body has not loaded yet.

```
var value = document.getElementById("uniqueID").value
```

You need to shift all your code inside the body load function.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="application/javascript">
        function OnLoad ()
        {
            setInterval(draw,120);
            var value = document.getElementById("uniqueID").value
            draw();
        }


        function draw() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

        if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.strokeText(value, 200, 200);
      }
    }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="OnLoad()">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="uniqueID" value="5" /><br>
 </body>
</html>
```